# Custom font, typeface doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, typeface, custom-font

Hello, Everybody. This is my code below, I'm using a custom font (arial) in my app, but something is wrong about my code typeface, maybe I put it in a wrong position (you all see it at the end of the code) or I missed some detail. I don't know. So, check it out! I need some help!

```
public class Listagem extends Activity {

    EditText edittext;
    ListView listview;

    String[] text;  
    String[] text2;

    int[] image = {
        R.drawable.wolf;
        R.drawable.cat;
    };

    int textlength = 0;
    ArrayList<String> text_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> text2_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> image_sort = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        text =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.text);
        text2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.text2);

        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                    if ("Howl".equals(text[position])) {
                        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Listagem.this, R.raw.howl);
                        player.start();
                    }

                    if ("Meow".equals(text[position])) {
                        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Listagem.this, R.raw.meow);
                        player.start();
                    }
                }          
        });

        listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text, text2, image));
        edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                textlength = edittext.getText().length();
                text_sort.clear();
                text2_sort.clear();
                image_sort.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                    if (textlength <= text[i].length()) {
                        if (edittext.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) text[i].subSequence(0, textlength))) {
                            text_sort.add(text[i]);
                            text2_sort.add(text2[i]);
                            image_sort.add(image[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }


                listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                        if ("Howl".equals(text_sort.get(position))) {
                            MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Listagem.this, R.raw.howl);
                            player.start();
                        }

                        if ("Meow".equals(text_sort.get(position))) {
                            MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Listagem.this, R.raw.meow);
                            player.start();
                        }
                    }
                });
                listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text_sort, text2_sort, image_sort));
            }
        });
    }


    class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        String[] data_text;
        String[] data_text2;
        int[] data_image;

        MyCustomAdapter() {

        }

        MyCustomAdapter(String[] text, String[] text2, int[] image) {
            data_text = text;
            data_text2 = text2;
            data_image = image;
        }

        MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> text, ArrayList<String> text2, ArrayList<Integer> image) {
            data_text = new String[text.size()];
            data_text2 = new String[text2.size()];
            data_image = new int[image.size()];

            for(int i=0;i<text.size();i++) {
                data_text[i] = text.get(i);
                data_text2[i] = text2.get(i);
                data_image[i] = image.get(i);
            }
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return data_text.length;
        }

        public String getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);

    holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

}
holder.text.setText(data_text[position]);
holder.text2.setText(data_text2[position]);
holder.image.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "arial.ttf");  
TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.array.text2);text2.setTypeface(font1);



return convertView;
}
```

}

}

Answer (score 1):

You can check this class

https://github.com/Neferetheka/Helper-Tools-for-Android/blob/master/FontManager.java

Then you just have to call the init method of the FontManager when your activity is created, and use the setTypeface method on your textviews